# Generate HTML pages locally, from a template and just change the title at the top of the page

Tags: html

I have a list of US cities and a template html page. Can I write a script that take a city name, generates a folder with the same name as the city, and place in that folder the template html page with the title in the head section set to the city name.

Comment: Yes, you can. Do you habe a plan with what technology you want to achieve that?

Comment: I need software that has this function

Answer (score 1):

Would it be more efficient to use that template and load it each time the page is called and simply pass the city name etc into that template?

PHP, or any MVC platform works beautifully for just this task, and avoids the need to create multiple directories/files of duplicate code..

If you absolutely, positively, need to generate all those repetitive files, you could easily write a program in C (or your preferred language) to iterate through the list of cities and scrape code from the template and paste it into a new file with a unique name for that city.

pseudo:
// open the list of cities
cities_file = openfile("citylist")

for (city in cities_file)
  // open template file
  temp_file = openfile("template")

// open/create new city file
  new_city_file = openfile(city.name + "-file")

```
// read line from template
x = copyline(temp_file)

// replace substring if "title" parameter appears
y = x.replace("<title></title>", "<title>" + city.name + "</title>")

// write line of city file w/updated text
writeline(new_city_file, y)
```

// close files
  closefile(new_city_file)
  closefile(temp_file)
loop

Of course, you can manipulate the files and directories any way you choose, it just depends on the environment you're working with.

For the sake of simplicity and efficiency, however, I would strongly recommend using the template as it's intended and simply populating certain items when it's rendered rather than creating multiple repetitive files. If, for example, you wish to change the copyright date at the bottom of each page, you would then need a script to update each of those various files instead of just updating the one template file.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply.

Can you give me a more detailed guide to be able to do this function?

-It must change the title according to the city

-It must change the name of the html file (example-page-city.html in this case only "city" needs to be changed)

-It must update the sitemap or:
<Url>
      <Loc> https://www.electro-web.it/example-page-city1.html </ loc>
<Lastmod> 02/11/2019 </ lastmod>
<Changefreq> Weekly </ changefreq>
<Priority> 0.8 </ priority>
   </ Url>